# Is it good practice to have different table types in a database with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am developing a game in PHP and of course there are about 1000 different tables I will need to create to store various types of data.  I heard, correct me if I am wrong, that InnoDB is better for tables that will be updated a lot because of row locking opposed to MyISAM's table locking.  However MyISAM is faster with selections.

My question is, should I just stick with one table type, or is it good to mix and match based on the needs of the table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is, should I just stick with one table type, or is it good to mix and match based on the needs of the table?

It's OK to mix.

`MyISAM` is faster for certain queries and supports `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL` indexes, while `InnoDB` is transactional and more concurrent.

In a database project I'm currently consulting there is a mix of tables for these very purposes.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your requirements. If you need row-level locking, foreign key constrains, etc you should go for InnoDB, but if you don't need it, you can go for MyISAM. Generally, InnoDB is way to go in most cases but nothing stops you from choosing multiple types of engines for your tables, ***that is beauty of MySQL***.

Comment: Agreed, use the tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can mix MyISAM and InnoDB in same database if required without any problem

Comment: Just to second the opinion, try using MyISAM for tables which are rarely used for data insertion/deletion, while use innodb for those that have frequent data updates. It will make the actual data safe and speed up processing for rest of the database.

Answer (score 0):

While you can mix tables, I'd stick entirely with InnoDB. While MyISAM can be faster for some queries, InnoDB is usually quicker if properly tuned. If querying by primary key, InnoDB will pants MyISAM for speed, since InnoDB stores data in primary key order. MyISAM may be faster for secondary indexes.

MyISAM doesn't support transactions, and if you have 1000 tables, chances are you'll be updating several tables as part of one operation, and all those updates should be done inside a transaction (or be prepared for major headaches when concurrency becomes an issue when your game gets busy or your database lags!).

Sticking with one table type also makes memory management easier on the database machine. InnoDB gets dedicated RAM for caching, while MyISAM relies on the OS file-system cache.

Using MyISAM for fulltext search on any kind of busy site will cause you grief. Instead, use [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/).